# Handling string objects and View Controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, modalviewcontroller

I am trying to pass a string back and forth between the view Controllers, so for example as soon as I click on a tab bar button (+) in the first View, second view opens (PresentModalViewController) and it has a Text Field. So anything I type, I take it into a string(this string is an object of the first view) and I am trying to append that string to a tableview loaded in the first View.

**Note:** My string object is declared like this

View1.h

```
NSString *string 

@property (copy) NSString *string;
```

View1.m

```
@synthesize string;
```

And in the View 2 I am passing the textField Value like this

View2.m

```
View1 *view1 = [[View1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"View1" bundle:nil];
view1.string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", TextField.text];
```

**Problem -** When I NSLog this value inside the View2, it grabs the value from the Text Field but in order for me to load the previous view, I need to dismiss this View2. So as soon as this View2 is dismissed when I try to access the same string object in my view 1. **It says the string object is null.**

**Question - Could someone tell me**
1. How to get the  text Field value from view 2 to view 1 after dismissing View 2 (does it really makes all its objects null when dismissed?)
2. How to append that string to the last index of a NSMutableArray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very good question that I also had trouble figuring out when I started coding for the iOS.  Basically, you don't need to initialize a new view1 because the tabbar controller already holds the view1 object in its `viewControllers` property.  Also, alloc/init'ing the string in not necessary in this situation.

Therefore, you would want to change this:

```
View1 *view1 = [[View1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"View1" bundle:nil];
view1.string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", TextField.text];
```

To something like this:

```
View1 *view1 = [self.tabbarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
view1.string = textField.text;
```

Or even:

```
((View1 *)[self.tabbarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]).string = textField.text;
```

---

Part 2:

> How to append that string to the last index of a NSMutableArray?

```
NSMutableArray *someArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[someArray addObject:string];
[someArray addObject:@"anotherString"];
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @chown will definitely work if the ViewController you're sending the string to is the base controller of a tabBarController.

If you were several levels deep into a NavigationController stack, then you'll need a different approach.

The approach I'd recommend would be to create a `protocol`. This is where you create a `delegate` of view2 to pass the string back down the stack before the view is dismissed.

There are loads of examples of this code both in the Apple Documentation and on the Internet (StackOverflow included) but here's a quick run down...

In View2.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

//define the protocol, so  you can set the delegate to this type
@protocol View2Delegate;

@interface View2 : UIViewController

//other properties etc

@property (assign) id <View2Delegate> delegate;

@end

//put the actual protocol definition here so we can pass a reference to ourself back up too if needed...
@protocol View2Delegate

- (void)view2:(View2*)view passingStringBack:(NSString *)stringToPassBack;

@end
```

In View2.m you can call that delegate method where ever you like but here's an example:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(self.delegate)
       [self.delegate view2:self passingStringBack:@"String I'm passing back"];

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Then in View1.h

```
@interface View2 : UIViewController <View2Delegate>
```

and View1.m

```
- (void)view2:(View2*)view passingStringBack:(NSString *)stringToPassBack
{
    NSLog(@"%@", stringToPassBack);
}
```

---

Another option would be to post a notification, but that is more a broadcast scenario than a targeted message so I won't bother posting example code for that.

Comment: Thats not a bad solution either.  A little extra work for the coder, but definately more modular!  Worth an upvt imo.

Comment: One thing though, in the `viewWillDisappear` method, the call to `super` should be at the end.  It doesnt really make a difference with the current SDK, and probably never will, *but*, it could eventually.  The general rule I follow is to call super first during view setup/loading, and call super last during teardown/unloading.

Comment: @chown you're right! That's what I get for coding in a text box instead of copying it from Xcode!